# swift: print words one by one

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I'm working on a trivia app and trying to print the question word by word.  Right now my code just prints each next word but replaces the one before it, so you only ever see one word at a time.  How should I make it so it still prints word by word but each previous word is still visible in the UILabel.

````
func printQuestion ()
    {
        let str = quizbrain.getQuestionText()
        let arr = str.components(separatedBy: " ")
        
        var count = 0
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { (t) in
            
            self.questionLabel.text = arr[count]
            count += 1
            
            if count == arr.count {
                t.invalidate()
            }
            
            
        }
    }```
````

Comment: `+= " " + arr[count]`

Comment: `self.questionLabel.text += " " + arr[count]` should work I think. I'm not 100% sure of Swift's syntax, but from my understanding it should support that operator.

Comment: Ah yes this worked, thank you!

Comment: I suppose I'll make it an answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append a space and the next word using `+=`

```
self.questionLabel.text += " " + arr[count]
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would work fine,

```
func printQuestion ()
{
    let str = quizbrain.getQuestionText()
    let arr = str.components(separatedBy: " ")
    
    var count = 0
    
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { (t) in
        self.questionLabel.text = arr[...count].joined(separator: " ") 
        count += 1
        
        if count == arr.count {
            t.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```